# Open data GeoRSS feeds

Tags: geospatial, geocoding

I am building a GIS platform for security management purpose. I would need to display POIs that would be geolocated about events occurring on the globe. Do you guys know open data geoRSS feeds available that I could use and import in my platform?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoRSS#Examples_of_GeoRSS_Implementations ??